# Single Term Off-Line Coins : Corrections on the final signatures

Tags: rsa, signature, blind-signature

I am making an implementation of Niels Ferguson's paper:  [Single Term Off-Line Coins](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_28) in Python.

In the Coin withdrawal protocol, in the last steps, Alice checks that the signatures she received are correct. She checks if she needs to adjust the signatures by making corrections. When I run the program I get most of the times that $S_{b}^{v} = C^{U}B$ but not that $S_{a}^{v} = C^{k}A$. I try to find calculations that need to change.

1. What are those corrections, and when and how do we apply them?
2. In the beginning of the protocol, we choose $h_{b},h_{c} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ of order $n$, for some prime $p$. However, it seems that at the step of finding a one-way function $f(.)$ that we consider $h_{b}^{b_{1}b_{2}}, h_{c}^{c_{1}c_{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$.This can be seen in the calculation of $e_{a}$ which includes $f(a)$, where $a$ is calculated $modn$ and because $p$ is only known to the Bank. Why did we make this simplification and why we chose $h_{b},h_{c} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ with the properties that are given in the paper?

Here is part of the code that I used to make the necessary changes. I use the following functions that are self-described:

```
    # Functions used
    fastPower(base, power, modulo), multInverse(a, modulo)


    e_a = (k_1_inverse * f(x_a) - tau)
    e_b = (f(x_b) - phi)
    e_c = (f(x_c) - sigma)

    if e_a // v < 0:
        g = fastPower(g_a, k_1, N)
        S_a = S_a *multInverse(g, N) % N

    if e_b // v < 0:
        S_b = S_b * multInverse(g_b, N) % N

    if e_c // v < 0:
        g_1 = fastPower(g_c, k_1 * k_2, N)
        S_a = S_a * multInverse(g_1, N) % N

        g_2 = fastPower(g_c, U, N)
        S_b = S_b * multInverse(g_2, N) % N
```